# Update query fields from data in SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen this asked before, but am unable to determine how to change this query to be able to update fields (clientid, program, startdate, & enddate) which are actually being returned in a SELECT statement used within the WHERE clause.  Any example of how to do this would be very helpful.  Thank you.

```
UPDATE baycare_homecare
SET
  IsApproved = 1
 ,ProcessDate = GETDATE()
 ,clientid = c.ClientID
 ,program = cp1.Description
 ,startdate = cp.startdate
 ,enddate = cp.enddate
WHERE
  Processdate IS NULL
  AND baycare_homecare.patient_ssn IN
      (
        SELECT
          c.socialsecuritynumber
        FROM
          carescope_live.dbo.client AS c
         ,carescope_live.dbo.client_program AS cp
        LEFT JOIN
          carescope_live.dbo.Code_Program AS cp1
            ON
            cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
        WHERE
          c.ulink = cp.clientulink
          AND baycare_homecare.service_date 
            BETWEEN 
              DATEADD(ss, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, cp.startdate)) 
              AND 
              DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(d, +1, cp.enddate))
      );
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
UPDATE b
SET IsApproved = 1
    , ProcessDate = GETDATE()
    , clientid = a.ClientID
    , program = a.Description
    , startdate = a.startdate
    , enddate = a.enddate
FROM baycare_homecare b
JOIN (
    SELECT c.socialsecuritynumber, c.ClientID, program = cp1.Description, startdate = cp.startdate, enddate = cp.enddate
    FROM carescope_live.dbo.client AS c
    JOIN carescope_live.dbo.client_program AS cp ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
    LEFT JOIN carescope_live.dbo.Code_Program AS cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
    WHERE baycare_homecare.service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(ss, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, cp.startdate)) AND DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(d, +1, cp.enddate))
) a ON a.socialsecuritynumber = b.patient_ssn
WHERE b.ProcessDate IS NULL
```

Updated query:

```
UPDATE b
SET IsApproved = 1
    , ProcessDate = GETDATE()
    , clientid = a.ClientID
    , program = a.Description
    , startdate = a.startdate
    , enddate = a.enddate
FROM baycare_homecare b
JOIN (
    SELECT c.socialsecuritynumber, c.ClientID, program = cp1.Description, startdate = cp.startdate, enddate = cp.enddate
    FROM carescope_live.dbo.client AS c
    JOIN carescope_live.dbo.client_program AS cp ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
    LEFT JOIN carescope_live.dbo.Code_Program AS cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
) a ON a.socialsecuritynumber = b.patient_ssn AND b.service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(ss, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, a.startdate)) AND DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(d, +1, a.enddate))
WHERE b.ProcessDate IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Eric.  When I try to save/run this, I get an error on the WHERE baycare_homecare.service_date line stating "the mutli-part identifier "baycare_homecare.service_date" could not be bound."

Comment: Change it to `b.service_date`

Comment: Actually it still may not work.  I'll update the query.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The only thing I had to update was the line program = a.Description to program = a.program and no errors.  I will test it out and mark this solved/answered.  I appreciate your time!  Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but I *believe* this is what you are after:

```
UPDATE bh
SET IsApproved=1
   ,ProcessDate = GETDATE()
   ,clientid = c.ClientID
   ,program = cp1.Description
   ,startdate = cp.startdate
   ,enddate = cp.enddate
FROM baycare_homecare bh
     JOIN carescope_live.dbo.client AS c ON bh.patient_ssn = c.socialsecuritynumber
     JOIN carescope_live.dbo.client_program AS cp ON c.ulink = cp.clientulink
                                                 AND bh.service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(ss, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, cp.startdate)) AND DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(d, +1, cp.enddate)) --this isn't SARGable
     LEFT JOIN carescope_live.dbo.Code_Program AS cp1 ON cp1.ULink = cp.ProgramULink
WHERE Processdate IS NULL;
```

Note that what you do is a "normal" `FROM` clause, with your `JOIN`s and aliases. Then, for your `UPDATE` clause you reference the alias instead. You can then reference the columns from the other objects with their respective aliases, like you would in a `SELECT`.